# Multiple SSH-keys on a ubuntu droplet

Tags: server, ssh

We are a team of four developers, who are working on a web project, which is to be deployed on a digital ocean droplet. ATM i have one set of ssh keys, which i created from my laptop, which i use to access the droplet, now my team members, also need to access the same droplet, would the best solution be for them to create their ssh key-pair, and configure them on the droplet? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: No time today to write an answer, but an elegant solution is using signed keys, see https://code.facebook.com/posts/365787980419535/scalable-and-secure-access-with-ssh/ or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu

Comment: As you are only four developers, I would recommend all devs create their own public-private key-pairs, and then installing the public keys for the devs on the droplet. You'll have to remember to remove keys (on all droplets) if someone leaves. With only 4 developers, I think other solutions would be overkill at this stage.

Comment: Okay thank you, i just have to add their public keys the the autorized_keys file in the ssh directory right?

Comment: it does not seem to be working? (i also asked a question about it https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027745/cant-access-droplet-after-accessing-ssh-public-key), might it have to do something with the permissions?